# ArgoCD Rollout how to deal with Environments

Tags: argocd, blue-green-deployment

I have a question how to deal with ArgoCD Rollout for different Environments.

For my continuous deployment pipelines, I follow the principles you can see in below image.

[image]

As explained in these blogs [blog1](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2023/02/05/ideal-ci-cd-pipeline-for-your-kubernetes-deployments/) [blog2](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2023/02/26/azure-devops-pipelines-for-an-ideal-ci-cd-for-your-kubertnetes-deployments/), in its current design the pipeline behave same for my all environments, 'dev', 'test', 'staging', 'production'.

I like to implement 'blue/green' deployments for 'production' environment but only for 'production', naturally I don't want to have different Helm constellations for 'dev', 'test', 'staging' and 'production' in Helm, so no 'rollout.yaml' for 'production' and 'deployment.yaml' for the rest, so I need a clever solution.

I can do something like that as [here](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-rollouts/blob/master/examples/helm-blue-green/templates/rollout.yaml)

```
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "helm-guestbook.name" . }}
      release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  strategy:
    {{ tpl toYaml .Values.rolloutStrategy . | indent 12 }}
  template:
    metadata:
```

and in 'values-dev.yaml' (or '*-test.yaml' or '*-staging.yaml).

```
rolloutStrategy:
```

and in 'values-prod.yaml'

```
rolloutStrategy: 
  blueGreen:
    activeService: {{ template "helm-guestbook.fullname" . }}
    previewService: {{ template "helm-guestbook.fullname" . }}-preview
```

but I am not really fond of this solution, can you think anything better?

Comment: to be honest, drifting release mechanisms between environments is something id be weary of - i develop expecting failure and that we will iterate on an initial implementation. In your above, where only prod has B/G, how do you improve this release mechanism? If you're worried about cost, then lowering requests/limits and replicas for lower level environments will help mitigate that concern.